# How to write registered user into database in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

When i select register.. the data is sent to Firebase authentication but does not store in the database? Can anyone tell me where im going wrong?

```
func handleRegister(){
        // Validation
        guard let email = emailTextField.text, let password = PassTextField.text, let name = nameTextField.text
        else{
            print("Please provide an Email and Password")
            return
        }

        FIRAuth.auth()?.createUser(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: { (user: FIRUser?, error) in

            if error != nil {
                print(error!)
                return
            }
            // Successfully authenticated user
            // Saving Data to the Database
            let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference(fromURL: "https://chat-47e5b.firebaseio.com/")
            let values = ["name": name, "email": email]
            ref.updateChildValues(values, withCompletionBlock: { (err,ref)
                in

                if err != nil {
                    print(err!)
                    return
                }

                print("Saved user successfully into Firebase")
            })
       })
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not doing it right, you should first get a reference to the db:

`self.ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()`

Then:

```
let values = ["name": name, "email": email]
self.ref.child("users").child(user.uid).setValue(values)
```

As a side note, convert this:

```
if error != nil {
   print(error!)
   return
}
```

To this:

```
guard let error = error else {
   print(error)
   return
}
```